# connect two agents via http-protocol in Java

Tags: java, http, client

I am working on a project in java that consists in connecting two agents via http-protocol using the following scenario:

```
1) http-agent1 make connection to http-agent 2 
2)  http-agent 2 send a GET-Request to  http-agent 1
3) http-agent 1 sends the asked resource to  http-agent 2 
4)  http-agent 1 stops the connection
```

can I do it according to http-specification?
I am a little bit confused, because I know that only one agent must be a listener and according to that scenario I do not know, which Agent must be a listener.

**I am using  java-sockets. So it really hard to separate between making connection and making request.!!!!!!!!!!!According to http-protocol, the agent, who is making request, should make also connection**

Answer (score 0):

Of course you can use http. But the term "user agent" only refers to a client, the and in the described scenario "http-agent 1" is a server, and "http-agent 2" send requests.

Here you can read http protocol: [Hypertext Transfer Protocol (HTTP/1.1)](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7230) the terminologi is explined at section 2.1

I cannot remember, but i think there is a class for http server and clients.

EDIT:

Ok, the link to the standar descrive http protocol, and should be implemented using sockets. Usually TCP sockets.

Java:

(Server)

```
    ServerSocket serverSocket = new ServerSocket(portNumber);
    Socket clientSocket = serverSocket.accept();
```

(Client)

```
   Socket socket = new Socket(hostName, portNumber);
   PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream(), true);
   BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(
       new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));
```

Both client and server got a Socket, but the server waits till the client wants to establish a connection and start exchanging messages.

The http protocol describes the kind of massages, the order and protocols used to communicate. Maybe you should start from reading about sockets Oracle java has a [tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/networking/sockets/)

Comment: I am using  java-sockets. so it really hard to separate between making connection and making request.!!!!!!!!!!!According to http-protocol, the agent, who is making request, should make also connection

Answer (score 0):

HTTP is typically used for client/server communication, which your example doesn't quite follow. In your case, you essentially have the following:

```
A connects to B
B requests from A
A sends to B
A closes connection with B
```

Basically, B is acting like the server (waits for connection) and the client (requests data) but part of your server functionality is also handled by A (actually serving data). The typical client-server version of what you are trying to do would go like so:

```
B connects to A
B requests from A
A sends to B
A or B initiate the disconnect
```

However, HTTP is just a communication protocol, so there is no reason HTTP won't work for your example. Its just not a very standard usage of it, so many of the frameworks won't be built to accommodate the exchange pattern you are building. It would be not too difficult to build up your own code to accomplish what you are using. You may want to look into the Java [HttpURLConnection](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/HttpURLConnection.html)

class

Comment: I am not using url. I am using sockets and I am making a GET-request

Comment: You can use a URL object, which you can pass into the constructor for HttpURLConnection, to connect to an IP and port (i.e., the same as a socket)